# Which UILabel method is invoked when I set text, and it resizes itself to fit?

Tags: ios, storyboard, uilabel, nslayoutconstraint

I have an UILabel, created in Universal storyboard, and I have mentioned all required **constraints** for its position **OTHER THAN WIDTH**. So it resizes itself as per the text set. Fantastic! Exactly what I want.

**Problem starts here :** It has background color as green color, but that color is wrapping my text tightly. I thus believe that making it a little wider can help me. But to do that, I need to know which method of my UILabel subclass is invoked. So that I can override and add additional width of 10 points.

**BottomLine:** Which UILabel method is invoked for resizing the label automatically after I assign it the text?

The way it currently looks :

[image]

Comment: can you post a screenshot, so that I can understand what you mean when you say "color is wrapping my text tightly"

Comment: Check edit, added the image

Comment: Provided that you are working with autolayout, you can also override `-intrinsicContentSize` and return a larger `CGSize` (based on `super`'s)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, we don't have any `contentEdgeInsets` property we can set on a `UILabel` (as we do have on a `UIButton`). If you want auto layout to continue to make the height and width constraints itself, you could make a subclass of `UILabel` and override the `intrinsicContentSize` and `sizeThatFits` to achieve what you want.

So, something like:

```
- (CGSize) intrinsicContentSize
{
    return [self addHorizontalPadding:[super intrinsicContentSize]];
}

- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size
{
    return [self addHorizontalPadding:[super intrinsicContentSize]];
}

- (CGSize)addHorizontalPadding:(CGSize)size
{
    return CGSizeMake(size.width + (2*kSomeHorizontalPaddingValue), size.height);
}
```

Note that this only touches the horizontal padding, but can obviously be modified to add vertical padding as well.

Comment: Sorry about the typos - it should work now. Let me know if you experience any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Steffen's answer is the way to go if you want to do that programmatically. I usually have a generic custom label subclass in my projects that adds a (`IBInspectable`) `contentInsets` property, amongst other things.

Anyways, just wanted to point out that you can also do this completely in IB by just wrapping your label in another view, give the container view the background color and add constraints for your horizontal padding.

Comment: This is a definitely a good approach if you prefer using IB. Thanks for pointing this out.